# Proper way to count environment steps / frames in distributed RL architecture for algorithms like CLEAR or LASER => modified impala with replay

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, policy-gradients, off-policy-methods

In classical - on-policy - [vtrace/Impala](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01561.pdf) algorithm `env_steps` are incremented every training iteration

like this : `env_steps += size_of_batch * unroll_length`

This works since every trajectory generated by workers is used for training only once in classical Impala.

However when we add replay_buffer to vtrace (like in [CLEAR](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11682.pdf) or [LASER](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.11583.pdf)) we also start to learn from off-policy data therefore some trajectories (from replay) could be sampled more than once.

My question is - does the env_step_counting stay the same even when some trajectories from batch are from replay and some directly from workers (on-policy) ?

Or do i count steps only on those trajectories that are on-policy => not from replay

like : `env_steps += len(batch["on_policy_samples"]) * unroll_length`

And if so what happens when i decide to use only samples from replay to train - how do i count env_steps then ? Using some kind of flag to indicate if specific trajectory was sampled already and leave it from counting ?

At the end of the day what i need to know is that should i count all steps of trajectories generated by workers (true environment steps) OR all steps of trajectories processed during training (training steps ?). - I need to know this in order to be able to compare results with other implementations.

Have been digging through the research papers for some time now and i haven`t been able to find what is the proper way to do it. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have decided to to collect both metrics - training_steps & environment_steps. In the end both could be used as performance metrics in one way or another. But i am still unsure which one of these were used in the deepmind science papers.